# How to avoid duplicate entry in database using insert in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a project developed in Laravel 4.2 where I have an array of records that I need to insert into a database using the built-in insert() function. However, I also need to update existing entries if they already exist in the database. Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this? Below is a sample of my code:

```
public static function followAllUsers($user_data) {
  $responce = array();
  $data = array();
  foreach ($user_data['following_id'] as $key => $value) {
    $following = UserBussinessLogic::checkAndValidateUser($value);
    if ($following != true) {
      $responce = Utility::Responce('invalid_user', FALSE, $value);
      break;
    } else {
      if (FriendBussinessLogic::isAlreadyFollowed($user_data['id'], $value)) {
        continue;
      }
      $data[] = array('follower_id' => $user_data['id'], 'following_id' => $value, 'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
      $followData['notifyAbleUsers'][] = $value;
    }
  }
  if ($following) {
    if (!empty($data)) {
      if (Friend::insert($data)) {
        $followData['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $followData['follower_id'] = $user_data['id'];
        $responce = Utility::Responce('friend_followed', TRUE, $followData);
      } else {
        $responce = Utility::Responce('general_error', FALSE);
      }
    } else {
      $responce = Utility::Responce('already_followed', TRUE);
    }
  }

  return $responce;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: post your database schema and your code

Comment: do post your code and database and the datas that you dont want to be inserted

Answer (score 2):

A little lesser known function that is also available in Laravel 4.2 is:
 [updateOrCreate](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L553)

Here's an example on how to use it:

```
// If there's a flight from Oakland to San Diego, set the price to $99.
// If no matching model exists, create one.

$flight = App\Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99]
);
```